# I am trying to switch to an existing branch on my repository on github but I am unable to

Tags: git, github

I am trying to switch to a an existing branch but it is showing me invalid path. The branch exists but I am unable to switch to it.

This is my terminal. The branch I want to switch too exists.

```
$ git checkout dev
```

> Error: invalid path 'content/blog/A message to Start-ups: Agro-financing is a viable market, but structural constraints continue to restrict investments.md'

Comment: the name of your markdown file seems to have some special characters. removing them may help

Comment: Are you on Windows? Do you know that file names on Windows cannot have a colon (`:`)? Choose more portable file names on whatever system you generated the repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Error%3A+invalid+path+windows